# How to understand what each layer is learning in a Deep learning neural network?

Tags: neural-network, cnn, mlp, deep-learning

In a recent answer I read on Stack Exchange, I read about a possible way to understand more clearly what happens in each hidden layer of a neural network.

Here's the excerpt-

> You should watch what makes neuron activated in each layer depending
>   on the input. As you know each neuron will be activated (once the DNN
>   is trained) for specific input combinations. By visualizing that you
>   can get an idea about what exactly each layer has learned in term of
>   high-low level features.

Source - [High-level features of a neural network](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26821/high-level-features-of-a-neural-network?newreg=9d25071f305146579053df8851a2b459)

I wanted to know if there are any papers who have tried doing this (links would be really helpful). Meanwhile are there any other ways to understand what happens in each hidden layers?

Comment: if you are working on images there is a python code for visualizing each layers input for each applied filter, I think this can be helpful. otherwise I think it's hard to exactly understand what each layer learns especially when you have a little knowledge about image processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to know if there are any papers who have tried doing this (links would be really helpful).

The best known paper on this topic is [*Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks*](https://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf) by Matthew Zeiler and Rob Fergus. But you can find many more papers and online articles that do the same.

> Meanwhile are there any other ways to understand what happens in each hidden layers?

Unfortunately, deep neural networks are like black boxes; we have little understanding of their inner workings. Visualizing the activations of the layers is probably the best way to tell what features they extract.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check out that paper.